# how to add a new product add page in magento admin side?

Tags: forms, magento, addition, product

The product add page is very large..can anybody help me to create a single product adding page in the admin side...

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento development doc to finish this job.
example:

use php code to get product:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
print_r($product);
```

and you can insert/update/delete product by php code.

[magento phpdoc](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/)